# Spring project error now that I am using Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-security

I am starting to use Maven to bring in my JARs into my projects. I have a Spring project that I move into a maven project in eclipse but I am now getting this error:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The classes from the spring-security-web jar (or one of its dependencies) are not available. You need these to use <http>: javax.servlet.Filter my-security-context.xml /WebFlowTemplate/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring line 12 Spring Beans Problem
```

this is the line I am getting it one:

```
<http use-expressions="true">
```

Here is my my-security-context.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">


    <http use-expressions="true">

        <intercept-url access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"    pattern="/helloworld**" />
        <intercept-url pattern='/*' access='permitAll' />


        <form-login login-page="/login.jsp"
            authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp" 
            default-target-url="/helloworld" />

        <logout logout-success-url="/" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="user" password="user" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>

        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

and here is my pom.xml file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springsource.greenbeans.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>WebFlowTemplate</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>WebFlowTemplate Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>WebFlowTemplate</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

it looks like everything is working but I dont want to see this error. Can someone put some information on this.

Comment: are you just missing javax.servlet:servlet-api?

Answer (score 6):

I also try many solutions to solve the problem.
But I found the solution, when I look into the maven dependencies of my project (I don't mean pom.xml -> I mean the dropDown-view in package explorer of STS).

There was no entry for servlet-api.

Put following dependency in my pom.xml solve the problem:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add Library "Server Runtime" in your project, and he work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I found this somewhat strange resolution to your problem:

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?110052-Configuration-problem-spring-security-web-classes-are-not-available-You-need

> Initially I thought I had an issue with spring security 3.1, but
>   actually it was because I was importing too many dependencies using
>   maven.
>
> Importing just a few required spring jars, cleaning and rebuilding the
>   project solved the issue, and I no longer get the error in my
>   application context xml file

Also check comments from this [blog](http://krams915.blogspot.ch/2010/12/spring-security-3-mvc-using-simple-user.html).

> you're following the Spring Security 3.1 tutorial, right? I suggest
>   doing a mvn clean to cleanup your project's workspace. Then try
>   building the project again